# angular material : bad scrollbar position

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my project based on angular+material, I just succeeded to position vertical scrollbar below the toolbar (with the help of sidenav).

But it does not work as expected for all cases.
See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pst9kr

- Home page : no scrollbar : good
- page2 : with lenghty text, one scrollbar on right : good
- page1 : centered images with strange scrollbars : bad !

Page1 has one horizontal scrollbar with firefox !?!
I expect to have one vertical scrollbar on the right and no horizontal scrollbar.
I need to center images, tables and text.

I tried to play with "width" for horizontal scrollbar but no success.

**Edit** :
Right ! In my project it was not working as expected so I was very puzzled, till I rewrote and did some cleanup.

1. I surrounded each page with 2 div:

```
<div class="page-container">
<div class="page-content">
...
</div></div>
```

2. I replaced "stdpage" with:

```
.page-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 64px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
  width: 100%;
}

.page-content {
  padding-right:  3rem;
  padding-left:   3rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By providing the `width: 100%` in your `stdpage` class work just fine. The Page 1 will get the vertical scrollbar properly after adding the width.

```
.stdpage {
  position: fixed;
  top: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
}
```